# Unable to create admin form using layout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminform, grid-layout, custom-admin-grid

**This Is Edit.php file**

> Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Demo\Edit.php

```
<?php
     namespace Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Demo;
     class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
      {
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

protected $_optionType;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Initialize cms page edit block
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{

    // /die("hello");
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'Magneto_BookFreeLayout';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_demo';

    parent::_construct();

    // $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Fields'));
    // $this->buttonList->add(
    //     'saveandcontinue',
    //     [
    //         'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
    //         'class' => 'save',
    //         'data_attribute' => [
    //             'mage-init' => [
    //                 'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
    //             ],
    //         ]
    //     ],
    //     -100
    // );
    $this->buttonList->remove('delete');

}


/**
 * Retrieve text for header element depending on loaded page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getHeaderText()
{

}

/**
 * Check permission for passed action
 *
 * @param string $resourceId
 * @return bool
 */

protected function _isAllowedAction($Id)
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($Id);
}

/**
 * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
 * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('bookfreelayout/*/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '{{tab_id}}']);
}


/**
 * Prepare form Html. call the phtm file with form.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFormHtml()
{
   // get the current form as html content.
       // die("hello1"); 
    $html = parent::getFormHtml();
    //Append the phtml file after the form content.
    // $html .= $this->setTemplate('Magneto_BookFreeLayout::demo/demo.phtml')->toHtml(); 
    // return $html;
}

/**
 * Prepare layout
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{

         // die("hello");
    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        require([
            'jquery',
            'mage/mage',
            'knockout'
        ], function ($){

        });

    ";
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
 }
```

**This Is Form file From where i am creating admin form**

> Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Demo\Edit\Form.php

```
   <?php

   namespace Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Demo\Edit;

   use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
   use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
   use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
   use Magento\Framework\Registry;
   use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
   use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config;
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]// use Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\A\Config\Status;

  class Form extends Generic implements TabInterface
  {

   protected $_wysiwygConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\Config\Status
 */
// protected $_newsStatus;


public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Registry $registry,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    Config $wysiwygConfig,
    // Status $newsStatus,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
    // $this->_newsStatus = $newsStatus;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);

  }

/**
 * Prepare form fields
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    // die("joooo");
   /** @var $model \Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\News */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('Alllayout');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('freelayout_');
    $form->setFieldNameSuffix('freelayout');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('General')]
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField(
            'id',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'id']
        );
    }
    $fieldset->addField(
        'title',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'title',
            'label'    => __('Title'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    );
    // $fieldset->addField(
    //     'status',
    //     'select',
    //     [
    //         'name'      => 'status',
    //         'label'     => __('Status'),
    //         'options'   => $this->_newsStatus->toOptionArray()
    //     ]
    // );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'summary',
        'textarea',
        [
            'name'      => 'summary',
            'label'     => __('Summary'),
            'required'  => true,
            'style'     => 'height: 15em; width: 30em;'
        ]
    );
    $wysiwygConfig = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig();
    $fieldset->addField(
        'description',
        'editor',
        [
            'name'        => 'description',
            'label'    => __('Description'),
            'required'     => true,
            'config'    => $wysiwygConfig
        ]
    );

    $data = $model->getData();
    $form->setValues($data);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Prepare label for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('News Info');
}

/**
 * Prepare title for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('News Info');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using ui components

Comment: @SohelRana ui component is not going to work because i have to show multiple images also

Comment: You can do everything using ui component. These php classes are deprecated. should avoid to use.

Comment: @SohelRana do you have any reference code or any module which will display multiple images uploaded from user and fetch them in from database and also display product name and sku using ui component